# What is the solution if $a=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have the equation $$x_n = a^nx_0+b\,\left(\dfrac{1-a^n}{1-a}\right).$$

I had to find the solution if $a=1$ and $a=-1$

- For $a=1$ we must divide by $0$ which is of course impossible, but I wonder; does that render $a=1$ 'solutionless' or does that term just disappear, leaving $x_n = x_0$ for $a=1$?
- Am I correct to say that for $a=-1$ we have the solution $x_n = - x_0 + B$ for uneven $n$ and $x_0$ for even $n$?

Comment: Hint: $a^n - 1 = (a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\ldots + a + 1)$, but you have to be a bit careful with this because technically $a=1$ is not in the domain.

Comment: @JohnMartin So that means $x_n = x_0$ for $a=1$?

Comment: Not quite.  Given what I wrote you have $\frac{1-a^n}{1-a} = a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\ldots+a +1$, so you will be evaluating $a^nx_0 + b(a^{n-1}+\ldots+a+1)$ at $a=1$.

Comment: But you do have to be careful, because in order to make this statement precise, one has to take a limit; do you know about limits and discontinuities of functions?

Comment: @JohnMartin A bit

Answer (score 1):

For $a=1$, as you have typed the problem, they will all be undefined.

For $a=-1$, and even $n$, we get 
$$x_0+b\frac0{1-a}=x_0$$ So you are correct their.
For odd $n$, we get
$$-x_0+b\frac22=-x_0+b$$
So you are correct again.